# Fennec: Javascript at end of page load

Tags: firefox, android, firefox-extensions, greasemonkey

I'm looking for resources (or even better an template-addon) on **how to run a simple Javascript 'Hello World' when a specific page has finished loading in Firefox mobile on Android** (Fennec).

Basically I'm trying to convert a Greasemonkey Userscript to a Fennec Addon. There **are** several pages that can accomplish this using PHP (e.g. http://geo.inge.org.uk/grease-vervet.php) but they're outdated as far as I can tell. Also there are some pages that would convert Userscripts to Firefox-Desktop Addons (e.g. https://arantius.com/misc/greasemonkey/script-compiler.php) but are incompatible with Fennec.

I've looked at several tutorials including of course the ones from mozilla.com but haven't had much success because they're very detailed for beginners such as me (also setting up a working programming environment including debugging as proven to be a pain). Also I have dissected several addons trying to learn from them, but I wasn't successful either.

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks,
Benjamin

-

similar question on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695159/mobile-firefox-fennec-add-on-executing-code-on-page-loads